# Выскакивает ошибка 401 Unauthorized при перезагрузке старницы

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, redux, mongo

У меня появилась проблема с JWT токенами. Когда я прохожу авторизацию и регистрацию всё проходит нормально, но когда перезагружаю страницу как и надо срабатывает функция checkAuth, она сначала возвращает ответ 200, а потом 401 Unauthorized.
[image: Ошибка]

Код:

Функция checkAuth в redux-slice:

```
export const chechAuth = createAsyncThunk(
"user/checkAuth",
async function (_, { rejectWithValue }) {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/refresh`, { withCredentials: true });
        console.log(response);
        localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.accessToken);
        return {
            isAuth: true,
            user: response.data.user
        };
    } catch (e) {
        return rejectWithValue(e.response?.data?.errors);
    }
}
```

)

Функция refresh в контроллере

```
async refresh(req, res, next) {
    try {
        const { refreshToken } = req.cookies;
        const userData = await userService.refresh(refreshToken);
        res.cookie("refreshToken", userData.refreshToken, {maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, httpOnly: true});
        return res.json(userData);
    } catch (e) {
        next(e);
    }
}
```

Функция refresh в сервисе

```
async refresh(refreshToken) {
    if(!refreshToken) {
        throw ApiError.UnauthorizedError();
    }
    const userData = tokenService.validateRefreshToken(refreshToken);
    const tokenFromDb = await tokenService.findToken(refreshToken);
    if(!userData || !tokenFromDb) {
        throw ApiError.UnauthorizedError();
    }
    const user = await UserModel.findById(userData.id);
    const userDto = new UserDto(user);
    const tokens = tokenService.generateTokens({...userDto});
    
    await tokenService.saveToken(userDto.id, tokens.refreshToken);
    return { ...tokens, user: userDto }
}
```

Функции для валидации токена

```
validateRefreshToken(token) {
    try {
        const userData = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_REFRESH_SECRET);
        return userData;
    } catch(e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Скриншоты слать не надо. Код надо прикладывать текстом.

Comment: пон, щас сделаю